# Cannot access meta from Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta

I seem to be unable to access any content on this meta site from the Android app. I thought this might be because we're in private beta, but I have no trouble accessing the metas of the other current private betas. If I open the site itself, the question list shows empty, and if I try a direct link to any post, I get

> Loading the question failed.

Especially during the rather meta-heavy private beta, this could be a bit of an issue.

As a side note, the meta question feed shows up differently in chat. Compare [this onebox from main](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23235331#23235331) with [this onebox from meta](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23239815#23239815). Just mentioning this because I figured these issues might be related. [Oneboxing meta answers directly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23243957#23243957) doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Meta.CG also can not be accessed from the iOS App. It says *Request failed. Tap to retry.* Also, when trying to add Meta.CG to the pinned sites the app displays an Error Message saying *The app submitted an invalid request. Please let us know on meta.* Tested on iPhone 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed as of build 2782 (it affects Community Building Meta too).

To enable the mobile apps to work, you have to clear cached data on the app.

[image: Android]